# Push notification does not receive (phonegap-push-plugin, ios, GCM)

Tags: ios, cordova, google-cloud-messaging, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to recive push from gcm on the ios.

I have registered my application there: https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=ios&cntapi=gcm&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fcloud-messaging%2Fios%2Fclient&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20GCM%20Support&%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue

uploaded p12 certificates, added obtained GoogleService-Info.plist to the root of ios xcode project.

```
var params = {
      "android": {"senderID": APP.senderId},
      "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true", "senderID": APP.senderId},
      "windows": {}
    };
var push = PushNotification.init(params);
push.on('registration', function(data) {
   console.log(data);
   ...
});

push.on('notification', function(data) {
   console.log(data);
   ...
});
push.on('error', function(data) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

registration is successful.

Then I'm trying to send push notification from my server:

```
public boolean send(String recipient, PushNotification notification) {
        LOG.info("sending message :" + recipient);
        Message message = new Message.Builder()
                .addData("title", notification.getTitle())
                .addData("message", notification.getMessage()) 
                .priority(Message.Priority.HIGH)
                .build();
        try {
            Result result = sender.send(message, recipient, RETRIES_COUNT);
            LOG.debug("result : " + result);
            if (result.getSuccess() != null && result.getSuccess() > 0) {
                return true;
            }
            if (result.getFailure() != null) {
                LOG.error("Error: " + result.getErrorCodeName());
            }
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(e);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following in the log :

```
16-06-06 20:28:32,868 INFO : [pool-2-thread-1] sending message :k3YUHDkEaR0:APA91bGSc9Wc3dvrS1-6EKBPL4Duu_xZDIujiUZjhkxaaHz3BS3n_ZciuQZLfFiEszXAX4kNUu7Oq0555jI3zzrgIVeNKtD0p63ftH6BPuhOXkCk-ujHlBTi9gSPRXJ6ixd_kTyCfrwS
16-06-06 20:28:33,246 DEBUG: [pool-2-thread-1] result : [ messageId=0:1465234217220513%ca70b4fbf9fd7ecd ]
```

But on the phone I get nothing. What I did wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the phonegap-push-plugin implementation. But since you received a messageId in your response on the server side then that indicates the issue is likely on the client side. Did you enable the receipt of remote notifications in your info.plist?

Comment: I have the same issue, I receive message_id, I enabled every single push notifications settings but still there is no notification. 

Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: I made additional sender that sends pushes directly to APNs without GCM